# Find the percentile of a value

Tags: python

I have an array of values like `[1,2,3,4,5]` and I need to find the percentile of each value. The output I am expecting is something like `[0,25,50,75,100]`.

I searched for an API in numpy that could get the desired result and found `np.percentile` but it does the opposite. Given a percentile value, it will find a value using the input list as the distribution.

Is there an api or way to get this? Thanks

Comment: your values seem off. Shouldn't it be `[20.0, 40.0, 60.0, 80.0, 100.0]` ?

Comment: So, like this but then for every value? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the zeroth percentile should be `1` as it is the minimum value in the list, right? And `np.percentile(range(1,6),0)` returned `1`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre using the function that @Caramiriel linked, `stats.percentileofscore([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)` returns `60.0` but `np.percentile(range(1,6), 60.0)` returns `3.4`. Why the difference?

Comment: `np.percentile(range(0,6), 60.0)` returns 3. Your 1 value isn't seen as the origin. 0 is the origin. Or the function shifts. I'm not a numpy specialist. scipy and numpy probably use different definitions/implementations of the percentile thing. If the function doesn't do what you want, just don't use it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre. Okay thanks, got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input can contain arbitrary numbers (e. g. `[3, 7, 13, 20]`) which are to be mapped to 0% – 100%, then you need to figure out the minimum number and the maximum number and stretch your values to 0 … 100:

```
values = [ 3, 7, 13, 20 ]
min_value = min(values)
max_value = max(values)
for value in values:
  fraction = float(value - min_value) / (max_value - min_value)
  percentage = fraction * 100
  print(value, percentage)
```

Or as a comprehension:

```
percentiles = [ float(value - min_value) / (max_value - min_value) * 100
                for value in values ]
```

This can also be sped up using `numpy` for large inputs:

```
import numpy as np

values = np.array([ 3, 7, 13, 20 ])
min_value = values.min()
max_value = values.max()
percentiles = (values - min_value) / (max_value - min_value) * 100
```

Comment: This is NOT correct. Take the following list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10]. 3 is clearly the median, aka 50th percentile. This method would tell you that 3 is the 30th percentile value.

Answer (score 7):

To get a value's percentile within a given dataset use [scipy's percentileofscore](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html).

```
from scipy.stats import percentileofscore

dataset = [1,2,3,4,5]

percentile_of_3 = percentileofscore(dataset, 3)
print(percentile_of_3)

[Output] 60.0
```

This output means that 60% of the values in the dataset are **less than or equal to 3.** percentileofscore's "kind" argument can be used to specify whether the percentile's cutoff should be inclusive or exclusive. For example:

```
percentile_of_3 = percentileofscore(dataset, 3, kind='strict')
print(percentile_of_3)

[Output] 40.0
```

means that 40% of the values in the dataset are **less than 3.**

If we want a list containing percentiles for each value, we can use list comprehension:

```
all_percentiles = [percentileofscore(dataset, value, kind='strict') for value in dataset]

[Output] [0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 60.0, 80.0]
```

(Thanks to Cobra for the edit advice!)

Comment: 2nd codeblock should say:

`percentile_of_3 = percentileofscore(dataset, 3, kind='strict'`)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `list comprehension` by dividing each of the list value to the `max(lst) -1`

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
max_val = max(lst) -1
lst = [(elem-1)/max_val * 100 for elem in lst]
print(lst)
```

Output

```
[0.0, 25.0, 50.0, 75.0, 100.0]
```

You can also achieve this using `numpy` arrays.

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
result = (arr - 1) / (np.max(arr) - 1) * 100
```

Comment: This is NOT correct, and only works under the very particular conditions that the values are perfectly evenly spaced, and that the lowest number in the sample is 1. This method will give wrong percentiles, and often negative values for percentiles, for almost any data except the example data given in the original question

Answer (score 1):

I take the definition of percentile (from wikipedia) as

> One definition of percentile, often given in texts, is that the P-th percentile ( 0 < P ≤ 100 ) of a list of N ordered values (sorted from least to greatest) is the smallest value in the list such that no more than P percent of the data is strictly less than the value and at least P percent of the data is less than or equal to that value.

So, for your data the answer is:

```
[20,40,60,80,100]
```

I also assume that you don't have a uniform distribution and number can repeat. You can get a dictionary to lookup the results using:

```
nbr = [1,1,3,4,5]
sorted_nbr = sorted(nbr)
ans = {x: 100*(1+i)/len(sorted_nbr) for i,x in enumerate(sorted_nbr)}
```

This yield:

```
{1: 40.0, 3: 60.0, 4: 80.0, 5: 100.0}
```

And if you need the list, then use:

```
[ans[x] for x in nbr]
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use [`np.true_divide`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.true_divide.html).

```
x = np.arange(5)
np.true_divide(x, 4)*100
[Output] array([ 0.  ,  25.,  50. ,  75.,  100.  ])
```